# Did the original Bem have a manga that was based on?

Tags: bem

As far as I know, the 2019 BEM series is based in a late 60's anime of the same name. Did that anime have an original manga version? Or did the story start with the anime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All *Humanoid Monster Bem* anime are original**, but they also spawned manga adaptation.

The first *Humanoid Monster Bem* anime in 1968 got its manga adaptation and was serialized in *Bokura* monthly manga magazine until 1969, then reissued by *Kodansha* in 2012 and got its paperback edition in 2010.

The second anime in 2006 got its manga adaptation and was serialized in *Weekly Young Jump* and *Mankaku*, then got its tankobon version in 2007.

The third anime, *BEM* in 2019 got its manga adaptation and was serialized in *Manga Park* application.

---

The manga spin-off *Humanoid Monster Bem RETURNS* was the only original manga, which was serialized in *Monthly Shonen Gangan* since 1993 until 1995. The anime (and game) adaptation was planned in 1997 but got canceled, and thus leaving only the manga.

---

Source: [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A6%96%E6%80%AA%E4%BA%BA%E9%96%93%E3%83%99%E3%83%A0#%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB%E7%89%88)